# How to install php and javabridge on Tomcat

Tags: php, tomcat, php-java-bridge

How can I set the environment variables of JavaBridge? what are the setting that can be changed for installing JavaBridge and PHP on Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably find that you'll need to set up Apache2 as the default web-server, and then use the Apache2-Tomcat Connector to pass any tomcat connections to tomcat.

As for the environment variables, it depends on the environment, is it windows or linux (and which flavour of linux)?